# Does texmaker support custom heading macros in its visual structure?

Tags: texmaker

If I use `\section, \subsection, \subsubsection, \paragraph` in a document I can turn on the structure view to see a hierarchical representation of the text divisions.

What if I have my own heading called `\general`? Could I add this somewhere?

```
\newcommand\general[1]{\newpage\section{#1}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. There is no user interface access to this set of keywords. But, although I strongly recommand not to do this, you can get the [source](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) of texmaker (it's available on the official webiste) and build in the support for the custom sectioning command to the document sctructure widget. You can compile it through Qt4 or Qt5. Otherwise you may just send a request to the developer: *pbrachet@xm1math.net*