# How to Create Section Tags in TexMaker from Another Command?

Tags: sectioning, texmaker

This is more for convenience on my part. I'm writing up my homeworks in latex using Texmaker and that involves sectioning parts of the homework as different problems. The document class I'm using, `jhwhw.cls` (found online) has a command `\problem{}` which will section the part of the paper as a new problem. However, the `\section` command is written inside the `\problem{}` command in the class, which means Texmaker doesn't register this as a new section in the structure view (sections of the structure found on the left panel in Texmaker).

How can I tell Texmaker that this command `\problem{}` is a new section? And if possible, how can this be done so that the labels for the sections will be 'Problem 1', 'Problem 2', etc. when viewed in the structure panel?

Thank you.

Comment: @JouleV Not sure it's strictly needed in my opinion, this is a problem with Texmaker, not code. You can see the effect if you add `\documentclass{article} \newcommand{\problem}{\section} \begin{document}  \section{Foo} \problem{Bar} \end{document}` to a document in Texmaker, only `Foo` is added to the structure panel. That said, this question is perhaps a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303812, and back then it seems the answer was that there no solution. I don't know if things have changed.

Comment: Normally, you do \section{Title of Section} and then on the left in the structure panel, a section is placed under "Blocks" titled "Title of Section". I wish to do this with the command \problem{} and have the section under "Blocks" be labeled "Problem 1". Note: the title of the section can't be placed in the brackets of \problem{}, so there has to be a different way to tell texmaker what the title of the  section is.